# Android端末(SH-01G)でURLスキーマ「comgooglemaps」が起動しない

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-maps

JavascriptでAndroid端末の場合URLスキーマ「comgooglemaps」でGoogle Mapが
起動しない現象が発生しています。以下のAndroid端末で発生しています。

[Aquos Zeta SH-01G](http://www.sharp.co.jp/products/sh01g/)

対象ブラウザは「chrome」で対象のJavascriptソースは以下の通りです。

```html
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > 0){
            alert('Google Mapアプリに移動します。');
            location.href = 'comgooglemaps://?daddr=' + 目的地緯度 + ',' + 目的地経度;
        } else {
            alert('Apple Mapアプリに移動します。');
            location.href = 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=' + 目的地緯度 + ',' + 目的地経度;
        }
```

実機でデバッグしたとこと、alertで「Google Mapアプリに移動します。」を表示することは
確認できておりますが、URLスキーマ「comgooglemaps」での処理でGoogle Mapアプリが
起動せずに終了しています。

原因が特定できず、対応に困っております。
もし対処方法がご存知でしたら、ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Comment: Google Mapアプリがインストールされていない　というケースはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ブラウザで特殊なスキームを持った URL をリクエストしてアプリを呼び出す、というのは iOS の機能じゃないかと思います。

Android では、ウェブ版の URL をそのままリクエストすれば、それに対応したアプリの（インストールされていれば）呼び出しが可能になります。ですので、下の Apple のマップを呼び出すらしき URL と同じようにすればうまくいくんじゃないでしょうか。パラメータなどは Google マップと同じみたいですし。

```
location.href = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + 目的地緯度 + ',' + 目的地経度;
```

Comment: ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。

URLを「https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + 目的地緯度 + ',' + 目的地経度」にすると
Google Mapに遷移することを確認いたしました。

助かりました。ありがとうございます。